# perl cpu profiling

Tags: perl, profile

I want to profile my perl script for cpu time. I found out Devel::Nytprof and Devel::SmallProf
but the first one cannot show the cpu time and the second one works bad. At least I couldn't find what I need.

Can you advise any tool for my purposes?

UPD: I need per line profiling/ Since my script takes a lot of cpu time and I want to improve the part of it

Comment: I wonder, how does it help you to see CPU time? [In this talk slide 7](http://cdn.oreillystatic.com/en/assets/1/event/27/State-of-the-art%20Profiling%20with%20Devel__NYTProf%20Presentation.pdf) it's said that CPU time is not a very good measure. Devel::NYTProf can tell you the times for each function/method call. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: How about Benchmark?  http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.16.3/lib/Benchmark.pm

Answer (score 1):

You could try your system's (not shell's internal!) [time](http://linux.die.net/man/1/time) utility (leading `\` is **not a typo**):

```
$ \time -v perl collatz.pl
13 40 20 10 5 16 8 4 2 1
23 70 35 106 53 160 80 40
837799 525
    Command being timed: "perl collatz.pl"
    User time (seconds): 3.79
    System time (seconds): 0.06
    Percent of CPU this job got: 97%
    Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:03.94
    Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
    Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
    Average stack size (kbytes): 0
    Average total size (kbytes): 0
    Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 171808
    Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
    Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 9
    Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 14851
    Voluntary context switches: 16
    Involuntary context switches: 935
    Swaps: 0
    File system inputs: 1120
    File system outputs: 0
    Socket messages sent: 0
    Socket messages received: 0
    Signals delivered: 0
    Page size (bytes): 4096
    Exit status: 0
```